# GLFW minimize window into systemtray/notifation area

Tags: java, windows, lwjgl, glfw, system-tray

Iam using LWJGL
I want to hide the window into the system tray (not the taskbar).

i tried using:

```
glfwIconifyWindow(windowID);
```

But that just minimize it to the taskbar.

then i found this one in the internet:

```
long hwnd = glfwGetWin32Window(windowID);
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
```

but this completely hides the icon it not appears in the system tray/notifaction area.